# Removing information from a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm using an API which uses the users IP address to find out the users Country Location and City, however I have never used regex before and I have no Idea how to extract the other information I want.

```
    $location=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$ip);
```

This line returns '**Country: UNITED KINGDOM (GB) City: Edinburgh IP: 80.192.82.75**' I have managed to extract the IP address using regex, but have no idea how to remove the Country and City into separate variables ($country = , $city =). Here is the code below I have so far.

```
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $location=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$ip);
 preg_match("/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/", $location, $matches); 
 $ip = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Why don't you use the JSON API at `http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php` and use a regular JSON parser for that?

Comment: I have no experience with JSON, would it be worth wile learning?

Comment: @Greg Yes. It's very simple, and if you just use `json_decode` you won't even have to learn it.

Comment: @GregValantine Well, the service provides it as an output format, and it's designed to be machine parseable. It's worth learning it if only because it's what fits your current requirements perfectly. (It's also currently a very common data interchange format for web APIs.)

Comment: @millimoose Thanks, will look it up on Lynda or check out some online resources for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the suggestion from [millimoose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41655/millimoose) it would look like this:

```
$jstring = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip='.$ip);
$ipinfo = json_decode($jstring);
```

And this gives:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [country_name] => NETHERLANDS
    [country_code] => NL
    [city] => (Unknown city)
    [ip] => xx.xx.10.9
)
```

This can be used as:

```
echo $ipinfo->city;
```

Comment: How would I get the country name into a variable from there? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: You have in in a var, just use $ipinfo->country_name

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `/Country: ([^\(]+) \(([^\)]+)\) City: ([^:]+) IP: ([\d.]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use Country:, City:, and IP: as delimiters.  If the API always returns all three fields, you could retrieve all of them in one shot:

```
/^Country: (.*?) City: (.*?) IP: (.*?)$/
```

Or if it doesn't, you might want to extract them one by one:

```
/Country: (.*?)(?: \w+?:)?/
/City: (.*?)(?: \w+?:)?/
/IP: (.*?)(?: \w+?:)?/
```

As far as the PHP part, matches from patterns in parenthesis are returned in the matches array per the documentation (except for patterns between (?: and ) ).  So Edinburgh should be returned in $matches[2] for the first given expression I listed above.

Note that additional escaping may be needed for the above strings, especially if they are put in double quotes, I believe.